# Use an alternate eval with nrepl

Tags: clojure, read-eval-print-loop, nrepl

I can pass `clojure.main/repl` a function that will be used to `eval` input (thanks to the `:eval` keyword). But how can I do this with `nrepl`? I read a bit about handlers but it quickly becomes hard and abstract to follow.

Also, since I mainly launch it with `lein repl`, is there a way to specify my `eval` in the `project.clj` file? `:repl-options` doesn't seem to accept the `:eval` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the interruptible-eval middleware: https://github.com/clojure/tools.nrepl/blob/master/src/main/clojure/clojure/tools/nrepl/middleware/interruptible_eval.clj

You could make something similar and start the nrepl manually using the start-server function. Or there is a lein option for nrepl middlewares.